# How to Manually Import Firebase Frameworks on Xcode 13.4

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, ios-frameworks, xcode13

I've been trying to import updated libraries to my Xcode Project. I have dowloaded the libraries from the official firebase site. I had multiple options but the developer of my App used manually import on the previous libraries. So I couldn't use cocoappos or nothing like it. Now Xcode is not finding the modules on my .swift classes when I import. But it shows them on the project navigator as libraries.

I tried relocating the .xcframework files to a folder named frameworks. Didn't work.
I tried understanding the file firebase.h and I cant figure out what it does.
I tried importing multiple libraries, it recognises some but others it doesn't.
For example No such module 'FirebaseMessaging'.

Comment: Why not remove the frameworks and re-add them via Swift Package Manager?

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Swift Package Manager with the specific version for your Xcode. It will avoid many headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cocoa pods for Firebase, it will not create problems with existing manually added frameworks until and unless the same framework is added twice(already added manually)